# Sending private messages using Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

Is it possible to send a private message (formerly called direct message) using the Twitter PHP API?.

I can't find any documentation on how to do this - i.e. how to send a private message to a single user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED : url was changed
[direct-message-api](https://developer.twitter.com/#direct-message-api)

Comment: Thanks!. this looks like exactly wha I have been looking for. One last quick question: how may I locate the id of a user?. For example, when I check my profile, I can't locate my id. where can it be found?

Comment: [GET users/lookup](http://developer.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup) by the looks of things.

Comment: Page Not Found. Try this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/api-features.html